# New laptop fan won't compensate for heat increase

Tags: laptop, fan, cooling, speedfan

I recently replaced my laptop fan because it was rattling, but the new fan does not seem to accelerate when I'm in game or doing any other power hungry tasks. My laptop is a MSI GE60. This makes the CPU go up to 100°C!

It worries me because I noticed a "burnt electronic" smell coming out of the fan exhaust while playing. I checked if the fan was running because it's really quiet, and it's indeed running, but a a fairly low speed compared to the old one. The new fan also does not react to the "fan acceleration" button on my laptop.

So far, I have not found any solutions online. I tried using Speedfan and checked "Automatic fan speed", but it does not seem to do anything.

I also checked the device manager, scanned for hardware changes and checked for driver updates for my CPU and my fan, but Windows told me I had the optimal version.

I saw many topics which mentioned that fan speed could be adjusted in the BIOS setup. Should I update my BIOS? It sounds dangerous to do, especially if it's unnecessary.

Comment: Can you be sure the proper fan was installed and properly? The behavior you mention does not sound normal, and is most likely because something wasn’t repaired properly. However, a simple load test by something like Aida64 or Prime95 while monitoring CPU temps should give the full picture. If the CPU is overheating, something is wrong.

Comment: Well, it was 3 screws and plugging it in a socket. I'm not sure how I could screw this up. Maybe it's not properly in the socket? I don't think so since I pushed pretty hard to make sure it was in. About the temp, I played a game for a little while to see how high the temp would go, and the Temp1 was around 100°C on SpeedFan and I think the cores were at 80°C but I don't remember well.

Comment: How many wires on the fan, how many on the socket?

Comment: 3 wires, 3 on the socket.

Comment: So, I did a 20 minutes stress test using Aida64, and I confirm that my 2 CPU cores went up to about 80°C and it looked like the temperature could have risen even more.

Comment: Here's a picture of the fan if you're interested : https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51t86%2BoY1ML._SX425_.jpg

Comment: if you pushed too hard plugging it in you may have broken the solder joint for the control pin (third wire) between the socket and the board. Also the replacement fan could be defective. Your CPU absolutely should not be running 100C. tjMax is usually 95-105C for Intel CPUs and expected operating temp is usually around 65-75C.